# Apply search filter for particular column in table vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I will be learning vuejs for the past few days. I have to apply search filter for particular column. In the grid component example given in vuejs documentation it searches all column. 
Tutorial Link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html

```
gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 }
    ]
```

I have to apply search only for `name` column. Can someone please help me to fix it. Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/xkkbfL3L/8621/)

Comment: I don't understand what problem are you facing. The fiddle is working fine

Comment: @Isaac I want to filter based upon `name` value. here see when i give `9000` in the search field it filtering the table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your computed property `filteredData` in this way:

```
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data
      // FILTER ONLY BY NAME
      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter( function (row) {
          return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterKey)
        })
      }
      // ==============
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  },
```

Here's the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkkbfL3L/8634/)

Answer (score 0):

made some changes in your computed property and used an array( if you want to apply search filter in more than one column).

P.S you just need to replace code for your filtering and make an array "searchableKeys"

```
  const searchableKeys = ['name','number']
  if (filterKey) {
    data = data.filter(row =>
      searchableKeys.some((key) => {
        const value = String(row[key])
        return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) !== -1;
      }));
  }
```

Here is the working jsfiddle in which filtering is done using 'name' and 'number'

https://jsfiddle.net/s63nfx7r/1/